# Database with cases of coronavirus (2019-nCoV)

Tags: virus

Does exist database with symptoms of 2019-nCoV (without personal data) and especially the duration of illness. How long it lasts? Who can access this data? I want to do some data mining(to calculate mortality rate, for example). Where can I find such trustworthy information about diseases like nCoV-2019?

Comment: Not exactly what you're looking for as it doesn't contain information about the illness itself but about the spread - https://gisanddata.maps.arcgis.com/apps/opsdashboard/index.html?fbclid=IwAR3aU7u4xpWmqSI7elfv7edaAI3ozjS5haG6wm2eChMKPOGJaAEw4luKki8#/bda7594740fd40299423467b48e9ecf6 also contains links to the sources (although mostly in Chinese) and the google doc which feeds the visual

Comment: US cases will most likely first be described in [MMWR](https://www.cdc.gov/mmwr/index.html). Confirmed cases are already reported, but we're not at a point where we have the full clinal course. China is not particularly good at sharing this kind of data.

Comment: Table S3 of https://www.medrxiv.org/content/10.1101/2020.05.22.20109777v1.full.pdf has cases but no duration however with references (that might contain this information).